# exiting from a blocking select call!

Tags: c, windows, select, sockets

I am calling a third party API which creates a socket, does a connect and then calls select API by passing the socket to block forever.

I don't have access to the socket. Is there some way in which I can make the select call come out from my application without having access to the socket?

My platform is Windows.

Comment: A couple questions / clarifications: 

(1) Is the call to `select` in code you can modify?  I *think* the answer is "no", but I want to make sure.  

(2) Assuming the answer to the previous question is "no", can you make the 3rd party api wait in `select` on multiple sockets that you specify? 

(3) From your question, it's not clear to me whether you use two 3rd party apis, one to create (and connect to?) a socket and the other to wait on one or more sockets, or a single api that creates, connects, and calls `select` without returning control to you.

Comment: Answer to your first question is No. I am using only one third party API which creates, connections and calls select without returning control to me. Thanks for your interest in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't normally do this unless you can access either the socket or the select set used.

If you can get access to the socket, close it via `closesocket()`.
If you can get access to the read set, stuff a dummy socket there, then see previous point.

If none of these work you can either:

- Ensure this happens in a separate thread, which you can later kill (although this will create some fairly obvious resource leaks)
- Attempt to override select using something like [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) (not recommended)
- Admit defeat.

Comment: I concur with Hasturkun.  I would also add the possibility of sending the blocking socket a message by pretending to be the other end of the connection.

Comment: How can I send it some message when I don't have access to the socket? Is there a way? Thanks!